# Error on creating job SQL Server 2005

Tags: windows-server-2003, sql-server-2005, tsql

Error on creating job:

```
Unable to cast object of type 
'Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.SimpleObjectKey' to type 
'Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Agent.JobObjectKey'.
(Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo)
```

SQL Server:

```
Microsoft SQL Server 2005 - 9.00.1399.06 (Intel X86) 
Oct 14 2005 00:33:37
Copyright (c) 1988-2005 Microsoft Corporation  Standard Edition
on Windows NT 5.2 (Build 3790: Service Pack 2)
```

OS:

```
Widnows Server 2003 SP2
```

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Install latest SQL Server 2005 service packs](http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/337192/unable-to-create-sql-agent-job-sql-2005-x64-with-sp2)

This Connect article refers to a some issues with the SP2 install but you appear to being the RTM version. Latest is [SP4](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=B953E84F-9307-405E-BCEB-47BD345BAECE)